# What is the import duty on computer hardware in India?

Tags: taxes, india, gst, customs

I find each international shopping site quoting different amounts as "Import Duty" for computer hardware (like processor, RAM and graphics card).

Amazon's global store calculates it at 40 to 43% of the product price. NewEgg's global store was calculating at 21% up until and a few weeks ago but have changed it to 45% now.

The [customs tariff page](http://www.cbec.gov.in/htdocs-cbec/customs/cst1617-300616/cst1617-3006-idx) on the government website doesn't mention anything about computer hardware.

So what is the current import duty on computer hardware?

Answer (score 1):

The import duty on most electronic components is zero. However these items still require to pay iGST of 18%.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have a source for this? I'd like to know what type of electronics attract an import duty and which are all exempted.